# Websocket, object Blob, utf8

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, websocket, клиент-сервер, сокеты

Есть websocket сервер, который отправляет сообщение в кодировке utf8, на javascript принимаю сообщение и вывожу в алерт, выводиться objetc Blob.
Как преобразовать полученные данные из utf8 в строку?

Comment: а как ты выводишь?

Comment: socket.onmessage = function(event) {
alert("Получены данные " + event.data);
};

Comment: function(event) { console.log( event.data); } что выведет? ну и пошаговая отладка должна показать что в event.data

Comment: Blob(426) {size: 426, type: ""}

Comment: что за сервер? строка подключения ws ? браузер?

Comment: Сервер на python, ws://192.168.1.189:886

Comment: полная строка подключения?

Comment: var socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.189:886");

Comment: браузер? отладка , точка остановки на alert("Получены данные " + event.data); просмотр  содержимого event

Comment: Зачем вам столько информации, я спросил как преоброзавать типы данных, с подключением все впорядке

Comment: затем, что если передается строка (а не бинарное сообщение) - то должна вывестись строка, а не объект.... если выводится объект - значит где-то есть ошибка. преобразования типов не требуется

Comment: Проблема была в том, что сервер отправлял не в str, а в utf8. Теперь отправляет в str и всё ок. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: нет такого понятия "str", unf8 - это и есть строковое представление. скорее всего что-то запутанное на сервере.